# Laravel 5.1 can't go to update() or destroy()

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am newbie laravel. I code a simple sample, but I can't go to update() or destroy()

```
My code

*At FilmsController*
public function destroy(Films $films)
{
   dd('die');
}

*HTML at delete screen*
<form method="POST" action="http://mylocalhost.com/public/admin/films/18" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="GHTF6XLpwqSukrgbXqRJWVEJWgsQk0XkUhmwJ530">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            Did you want to delete this item?<br>
            <element class="btn btn-warning btn-sm close_popup">Cancel</element>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My route

```
Route::resource('films', 'Admin\FilmsController');
```

I've used

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:list
```

-> i think so it's no problem
[image: Route:list]

I can't go to destroy() show "die" when i click at "Delete" button.
Please help me, thanks all of you

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: No any error information in screen

Comment: try changing your `destroy` method to this `public function destroy($films)`

Comment: I've use : Route::model('films', 'App\Films'); => So, destroy(Films $films) no problem